# Keras CNN high training accuracy / low validation accuracy / high testing accuracy

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, keras

I know the situation "high training accuracy / low testing accuracy" is overfitting.

But when I train my model.My situation is

"high training accuracy (0.94) / low validation accuracy (0.13) ".

And I use this model to test new image.The testing result is well (about 0.89 accuracy).

Why?

Comment: Sample sizes? Have you tried with different train/val/test splits? What is your task and data like?

Comment: Perhaps your validation set is too small or is not representative of the actual data

Answer (score 0):

Please check the preprocessing function that is being used for processing the data using generator.

Also scale the data before feeding it to the model.